# How do I sign out of stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

Signing up or Logging in is straight forward. You click on the corresponding button at the top-right of the screen. Now how do I sign/log-out? Clicking my avatar takes me to some profile page. And no, there is no sign-out button/link there. Is this one of those sites where you have to go deleting your cookies to get out?

P.S. And why is there no tag for discussing the usage of this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top right of your screen - button that looks like a speech bubble with 3 lines going through it (next to the question mark) - click that and there should be a log out option.

Discussing the usage of this site should be done on [meta.superuser.com](https://meta.superuser.com/).

Comment: Yes, found it. This is very unintuitive though. The icon looks like some chat feature and the pop-up alt text reads "A list of all 176 Stack Exchange sites". thanks anyway.

Comment: Unintuitive, aye.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.